# Get specific results from 3rd party website

Tags: search

I am trying to get results from [realtor.ca](https://www.realtor.ca/) for all houses that were built between 2000 and 2013. The advanced search does not have this feature, but I am trying to see if it is possible to add the search criteria in the URL.

I looked at the source code and the id for the value seems to be `builtin_value`. So, I added `&builtin_value=2000,2011,2012,2013` to the URL string but this did not work.

Comment: Hi Ron, I'm not trying to be rude, but this isn't really a programming question, which is what this site is for. I would close this question and just use the Contact Us form on realtor.ca at "https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/ContactUs.aspx#".

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Yes, I see your point that this may not seem like a programming question. However, I am asking the question from a programming point of view as I am writing a program that aggregates this information. Yes, I did contact the website but unfortunately they do not offer assistance on this matter. Hence, I was hoping someone on here could figure it out.

Comment: Fair enough. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around with the site's URL structure for a little bit, I agree that you can't add the `builtin_value` parameter to the URL and there doesn't seem to be an equivalent.

That being said, I think that in this case, the `Keywords` text box is your friend. I tried doing some sample searches entering *2001* as the value for the `Keywords` text box and only got back houses that were built in 2001 - same with experiments for other years. You can exploit the fact that nobody enters numbers like 2001 unless it's in the context of the year the house was built in. The exception to this is for the year 2000, however. Entering the keyword *2000* comes back with a plethora of results, including every house with approximately 2000 square feet. Thus, if you can wriggle a relaxation of requirements out of your project manager or boss where you only need years built excluding 2000, then I think that you could write a relatively simple program which just executes a request for each year (i.e. a for loop iterating over the years 2000 to 2013), accepting the `GET` responses at face value, and paging the data as needed by incrementing the `CurrentPage` URL parameter until you don't get anymore results.

If you *really* need the year 2000 then you could write a scraper that is more sophisticated than what I am proposing above. It would have to `GET` each search result and vet that it was indeed built in the year 2000.

For example, consider the following URLs:

1. A search for all houses in Vancouver built in 1971: https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/Map.aspx#CultureId=1&ApplicationId=1&RecordsPerPage=9&MaximumResults=9&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&StoreyRange=0-0&BedRange=0-0&BathRange=0-0&Keywords=1971&LongitudeMin=-123.2340278625491&LongitudeMax=-122.85396957397488&LatitudeMin=49.21465057441378&LatitudeMax=49.34746245927539&SortOrder=A&SortBy=1&viewState=m&Longitude=-123.043998718262&Latitude=49.2811012268066&ZoomLevel=12&CurrentPage=1
2. A search for all houses in Canada built in the year 2000 (lots of non-relevant results) on page 3: https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/map.aspx#CultureId=1&ApplicationId=1&RecordsPerPage=9&MaximumResults=9&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&StoreyRange=0-0&BedRange=0-0&BathRange=0-0&Keywords=2000&LongitudeMin=-135.1318359375&LongitudeMax=-37.8369140625&LatitudeMin=44.707725934249424&LatitudeMax=70.92742296535133&SortOrder=A&SortBy=1&viewState=m&CurrentPage=3
3. A search for all houses in Canada built in the year 2001: https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/map.aspx#CultureId=1&ApplicationId=1&RecordsPerPage=9&MaximumResults=9&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&StoreyRange=0-0&BedRange=0-0&BathRange=0-0&Keywords=2001&LongitudeMin=176.220703125&LongitudeMax=10.810546875&LatitudeMin=4.483729141145389&LatitudeMax=72.9471586872288&SortOrder=A&SortBy=1&viewState=m&CurrentPage=2

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the help. This was my Plan B and maybe I have to go with it. As you mentioned it will contain some margin of error and this is what I was trying to avoid, but it maybe the only option beside applying for their Api.

Comment: While it does contain a margin of error, if you drill down and crawl the detail pages of the houses, themselves, you can really minimize the margin of error by double checking the values in the search. Of course, this will take both more development time and execution time.